# Why doesn't my approach for solving this problem work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

Here's the problem:

[image]

Let the radius of the fixed sphere be $R$, the angle the ball makes from the vertical be $\theta$, and the angular velocity of the ball around its center of mass be $\omega$.

My approach is this. At some point, the normal force from the sphere will go to zero and the ball will leave the sphere. At this point, since no friction from the sphere is acting on the ball, $\dot{\omega} = 0$. If I find this point, I am done.

From the no-slipping condition we have
\begin{align*}
(R + r)\dot{\theta} & = r\omega \\~\\
\implies \dot{\theta} &= \frac{r}{R + r} \omega
\end{align*}

From conservation of energy we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{m}{2}(R + r)^2 \dot{\theta}^2 + \frac{1}{2}(\beta mr^2)\omega^2 & = mg(R + r)(1 - \cos\theta) \\~\\
\implies \frac{1}{2}r^2 \omega^2 (1 + \beta) & = g(R + r)(1 - \cos \theta) \\~\\
\implies \omega^2 & = \frac{2g(R + r)}{r^2 (1 + \beta)}(1 - \cos \theta) \\~\\
\implies \omega &= \frac{1}{r}\sqrt{\frac{2g(R + r)}{1 + \beta}} \cdot \sqrt{1 - \cos \theta} \\~\\
\implies \dot{\omega} &= \frac{1}{r}\sqrt{\frac{2g(R + r)}{1 + \beta}} \cdot \frac{\sin \theta}{2 \sqrt{1 - \cos \theta}} \dot{\theta}
\end{align*}

However, this means that the ball will only leave the sphere when $\theta = \pi$ which is completely wrong.

Comment: How did you conclude it leaves the sphere at $\theta = \pi$? You can find from force analysis that the ball leaves when $m\omega^2 (R+r) = mg \cos\theta$ and you have found $\omega$ which should result in the answer of $\cos\theta = \frac{2}{3 + \beta}$. Analyzing the change in angular velocity itself is not really significant because the ball can still be rotating about some point even after it leaves the sphere.

Comment: I know. That's what I did later. The angular velocity of the ball about an axis passing through its COM doesn't change after the ball leaves the sphere. Its angular acceleration around its COM must be zero right before it leaves the sphere.

Comment: I get that $\dot{\omega} = 0$ only when $\sin \theta = 0$ as you can see from the last equation in my post.

Comment: Your condition that the ball will leave when the normal force is zero is correct, but I don't follow your argument that $\dot{\omega}=0$ at that point. The normal force is zero, and friction (proportional to the normal force) is zero, but there is still gravity providing a net downward force.

Comment: How could gravity cause a nonzero $\omega$? The gravitational force produces zero torque around the axis passing through the ball's COM.

Comment: "cause a nonzero $\dot{\omega}$". Can't seem to edit my comment for some reason.